# What is the equivalent of c# CreateGraphics in Delphi?

Tags: c#, delphi, graphics

```
  public PictureBox pic;
  private Graphics gr;
  private Pen p;
  ...
  gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
  p = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
```

Is there a possibility to write this in Delphi?

Comment: Source language? PictureBox1 declaration? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls (and classes like TBitmap), intended for drawing, have Canvas property (rough Graphics analog), and you don't need to create it.
The same is true for Pen, Brush, and other Canvas properties. Just change Pen.Color when needed.